# localStorage sobreescribe mi objeto en el array, en vez de crear uno nuevo

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Tengo el array bugs con un JSON lleno de bugs para renderizar por pantalla en caso de que no haya elementos en mi localStorage:

```
const bugsToRender = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bugs')) || bugs;
```

Tengo también mi clase Bug

```
class Bug {
constructor(id, name, project, status, due, responsible) {
    this. id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.project = project;
    this.status = status;
    this.due = due;
    this.responsible = responsible;
}};
```

Cada vez que añado un bug mediante un form, lo añade al array de bugs y al array de localStorage:

```
const addBug = () => {
const bugId = chance.guid();
const bugName = document.getElementById('bug-name').value;
const bugProject = document.getElementById('projects-options').value;
const bugStatus = document.getElementById('status').value;
const bugDue = new Date(document.getElementById('due').value);
const bugResponsible = document.getElementById('responsible').value;
const alertBug = document.getElementById('alertBug');

//Si los campos están llenos, crea un nuevo Bug y lo añade al array
if (bugName && bugProject && bugStatus && bugDue && bugResponsible) {
    const newBug = new Bug(bugId, bugName, bugProject, bugStatus, bugDue, bugResponsible);
    bugs.push(newBug);
    localStorage.setItem('bugs', JSON.stringify(bugs));
    bugsToRender = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bugs'));
    document.getElementById('form-bug').reset();
    modalBug.classList.remove('active');
    fetchBugs();
    fetchResults();
} else {
    alertBug.innerHTML = 'Por favor, rellena todos los campos'
};};
```

Cuando añado un bug desde cero, funciona perfecto; pero al momento de añadir otro más, reemplaza ese último. Me fijé en el almacenamiento local y efectivamente lo sobreescribe.

La función para pintarlos por pantalla es esta:

```
const fetchBugs = () => {
bugTable.innerHTML = '';

bugsToRender.forEach((bug) => {
    bugTable.innerHTML += `<tr>
    <td class="bug-name">${bug.name}</td>
    <td class="status">
        <div onclick="openModal('modal-status')" class="estado ${bug.status}">${bug.status}</div>
    </td>
    <td class="date">${new Date(bug.due).toLocaleDateString()}</td>
    <td class="responsable">${bug.responsible}</td>
    <td id="trash" onclick="deleteBug()"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>
    </tr>
    `
})
fetchResults();
```

};

Comment: Tiene pinta de que este error tipográfico en el constructor te esta causando ese comportamiento: `this. id = id;`... si te fijas tienes un espacio y realmente no estas asignando la propiedad `id` al objeto.  Ponlo sin espacio y prueba de nuevo:  así:  `this.id = id;`

Comment: Gracias por la observación! Pero me lo sigue sobreescribiendo, no era ese el error

Comment: ¿En esta línea `bugs.push(newBug);`, de dónde sale la variable de `bugs`? No la veo nunca en tu código. Creo que por ahí está el error. Te recomiendo sustituir esa línea por una lectura directa al localStorage en ese momento. Ejemplo: `bugs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bugs'));` y luego haces el `bugs.push(newBug);`,

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez ponle una respuesta con lo que has dicho en tu comentario, tiene toda la pinta de ser eso, gracias